# Bash: I want to count letters and substitute text

Tags: bash, snort

OK so I'm extremely new to bash shell scripting and I've been pretty successful up until this point.  I'm using BASH to fix a problem...

I want to turn a basic domain name:
Buddies.forlife.com 
into
|07|Buddies|07|forlife|03|com

Basically, I need it to count the letters and convert it to hex. To be clear, Not convert the domain name to hex, but the letter count to hex.  I'm having a hard time replacing the period "."

I hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve...

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: So you solved the counting, and want us to tell you how to replace the periods?

Comment: Well Both if possible.  I hand jammed those numbers in to demonstrate the outcome I'm looking for.

Comment: Oh and the count is in hex so after the numbers... 0a, 0b.... u get the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward way to do this using awk

```
echo "Buddies.forlife.com" | awk -F '.' '{ printf( "|0x%x|%s|0x%x|%s|0x%x|%s\n", length($1),$1, length($2),$2, length ($3), $3 )}'
|0x7|Buddies|0x7|forlife|0x3|com
```

The awk command is setting the field separator `-F '.'` to a period, so each segment is considered it's own field.

We can then refer to those fields by `$1, $2 and $3`, use the builtin function `length` to get the character count for each field, and use a printf to print out the results (`%x` for hex numbers, `%s` for the original strings, and output field separation using the '|' symbol, in the format you had specified.

The `0x`prefix is typically used to indicate hex numbers, but can be changed to something else (or nothing) as needed.